# Compare multiple inputes againts one with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want is the following things: In my situation, I need the day, month and year to match those written in the SSN field. All of the data is user input. My code looks like this so far:

```js
function SSNcheck(){
          if (document.getElementById('SSN').value == "" ||
        document.getElementById('SSN').value.length !== 13){
     alert('Invalid SSN: Make sure you have 13 characters');
     return false;
    }
}

function Daycheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Day').value.length !== 2 || 
        document.getElementById('Day').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Day: Make sure the day is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}

function Monthcheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Month').value.length !== 2 || 
        document.getElementById('Month').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Month: Make sure the month is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}

function Yearcheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Year').value.length !== 4 || 
        document.getElementById('Year').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Year: Make sure the year is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
  <div id="SSN box">
    <form method="post" 
       onsubmit="SSNcheck() || Daycheck() || Monthcheck() || Yearcheck()" >
    Please insert your SSN here: 
      <input type="textbox" 
             id="SSN" 
    placeholder="Must contain 13 characters" 
    onchange="SSNcheck"
    maxlength="13"
    size="19"
    onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"/> <br/>
 <p></p>
 Day: <input type="number" 
             id="Day"
    onchange="Daycheck"
    maxlength="2"
    size="2"
    onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
    min="1" max="31"
    "/>
 Month: <input type="number" 
               id="Month"
      onchange="Monthcheck"
      maxlength="2"
      size="2"
      onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
      min="1" max="12"/>
 Year: <input type="number" 
              id="Year"
     onchange="Yearcheck"
     maxlength="4"
     size="4"
     onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
     min="1" max="2016"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Verify">
 </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "match those written in the SSN field"? The SSN is just a 13 digit number.

Comment: Have you thought of first adding the, day, month and year together. So it would look like 01012001 and then write a code to compare it with the ssn?

Comment: In this case the SSN represents the Social Security Number or someones personal ID, i'm not allowed to put them together, the user needs to put his SSN in and base on that he needs to verify it once again and then submit it, it's simillar to " password and verify password" kind of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for?

also there was a " to many in your html code

```js
function SSNcheck(){
          if (document.getElementById('SSN').value == "" ||
        document.getElementById('SSN').value.length !== 8){
     alert('Invalid SSN: Make sure you have 13 characters');
     return false;
    }
}

function Daycheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Day').value.length !== 2 || 
        document.getElementById('Day').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Day: Make sure the day is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}

function Monthcheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Month').value.length !== 2 || 
        document.getElementById('Month').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Month: Make sure the month is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}

function Yearcheck(){
       if (document.getElementById('Year').value.length !== 4 || 
        document.getElementById('Year').value == ""){
    alert('Invalid Year: Make sure the year is similar with the one from SSN');
    return false;
    }
}

function Compare(){
  var day = document.getElementById('day');
  var month = document.getElementById('month');
  var year = document.getElementById('year');
  var result1 = document.getElementById('result');
  var ssn = document.getElementById('ssn');
  
  var date = day.value + month.value + year.value ;
  
    if (date == ssn.value){
        alert('SSN is correct');
    return false;
  }else{
        alert('SSN is incorrect');
    return false;
  }
  

};
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
  <div id="SSN box">
    <form method="post" 
       onsubmit="SSNcheck() || Daycheck() || Monthcheck() || Yearcheck()" >
    Please insert your SSN here: 
      <input type="textbox" 
             id="SSN" 
    placeholder="Must contain 13 characters" 
    onchange="SSNcheck"
    maxlength="13"
    size="19"
    onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"/> <br/>
 <p></p>
 Day: <input type="number" 
             id="Day"
    onchange="Daycheck"
    maxlength="2"
    size="2"
    onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')
    min="1" max="31"
    "/>
 Month: <input type="number" 
               id="Month"
      onchange="Monthcheck"
      maxlength="2"
      size="2"
      onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
      min="1" max="12"/>
 Year: <input type="number" 
              id="Year"
     onchange="Yearcheck"
     maxlength="4"
     size="4"
     onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
     min="1" max="2016"/>
 <input type="submit" onclick="Compare()" value="Verify">
 </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I want from my code. I took the " out of my html code and changed everything as you did, the only problem is that despite the values i put in or if don't put any in the code says that the SSN is correct, it only checks if they have the same length. but this is a big help ! i will try to work around it, I probably need an ".indexOf" somewhere there

Comment: @SiposStelian I've changed my code, now it works properly.

Comment: you did solve that problem but now my SSN is correct only if all my fields are blank, otherwise no matter what combination of numbers I insert and then I repeat it, it's says that SSN is incorrect. Also if my SSN would be 1820315498231 my day number would be on position 5-6(15), month on 3-4(03) and year on 0-2(182 which would represent 1882). makes everything so much harder. Thank you for you time anyway, you really helped me a lot

Comment: Strange if you check my codepen: http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/PmzvpW you can see that it works perfectly, but if my awnser solved your question you should check it :)

Comment: Thank you for your time @Notorious_Creed ! Best of luck in everything you do !

Comment: Thank you @SiposStelian! You too!